# What are Apache Phoenix many-to-many design best practices?

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I am new to Apache Phoenix and fairly new to HBase. 
According to HBase best practices you have to design your tables around queries, which involves tables denormalization.
Apache Phoenix does support joins, what makes possible to design data model with relational approach.

Let's say you have a student that can attend many courses and a course that can have many students.
In a relational world my tables would look like:

Student:

```
student_id | fname | lname | dob
```

Course:

```
courde_id | name | description | start_date
```

StudentCourceAssociation:

```
student_id | course_id
```

Should I create the same data model in Phoenix or should I go with more NOSQL approach?

I think I could have only 2 tables: Student and Course. 
Student table could have a column family 'student_course' with dynamic columns, where each dynamic column name would be an id of the course that student has enrolled.
Or as one more alternative, I could store relationship information in a column of type SQL Array.

It would be nice to hear from someone who can give some guidance. I'd like to know which approach is preferred and why.